# Stop Google Autofill from overwriting fields with existing values on a react form

Tags: reactjs, forms, autofill, react-jsonschema-forms

I have a simple form in react, which lives in a modal. If a user was to use autofill for an email field for example, it would update other fields including fields that I've already filled in. This would lead users to submitting data, not knowing that fields out the view have been updated.

I've tested this in non-react forms and Google Autofill works fine, in that it would not overwrite existing values in fields. But in react lets say I inserted firstname = john, and then use autofill on the email...it would over 'John' and use whatever is saved in Autofill.

Is anyone aware of a way around this? I'm not going to turn autocomplete off as I still want users with the ability, anyway I've tried variations of autocomplete=off as suggested else where but still no result

Answer (score 0):

You can use autocomplete="off" in your input that you do not wish to autofill.

Please also make sure your input types are correct.

example: `<input type="text" name="foo" placeholder="foo" autocomplete="off">`

You can even do this using JS:

inputElm.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "off" );

as an example.

regards

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Try to create hidden input right before your input and add random number for your original input name where you don't want Chrome to autofill values:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="" readOnly={true} style={{display: "none"}}/>
<input
  type="text"
  name={"address " + Math.random()}
/>
```